# SONAR "SQL Injection" smell for jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query)

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have below code which gets all the results from a database table into `List<Map<String, Object>>` format using `jdbcTemplate`.

```
String query = "select * from my_table";
List<Map<String, Object>> results = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
```

This piece of code (second line) gives vulnerability of SQL Injection into SONAR.

Is there any way to reformat this code?
I need the results in `List<Map<String, Object>>` format only as per the current implementation.

Comment: See [the sonar rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3649). It has examples and explanations. It seems that the rule simply checks for queries passed as Strings - just create a prepared statement instead.

Comment: This is a false positive, ignore it in Sonar.

Comment: Suppressing it should be ok here - just make sure that the next Developer doesn't add a parameter to the query without removing the suppression - but that has to be covered by code review.